# How to use solana-ledger-tool to modify genesis.bin?

Tags: solana-cli, solana-test-validator, ledger

I'm trying to modify the `genesis.bin` parameters but there isn’t specific documentation.

But I can see `modify-genesis` as an available sub-command but can’t figure out how to use it to modify `Cluster type` and `Creation time`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out. I am answering my own question hoping that someone will find it helpful.

```
solana-ledger-tool --ledger ledger-directory/ modify-genesis --cluster-type development --hashes-per-tick "sleep" OUPUT_DIRECTORY
```

- Possible values for cluster Types: `development`, `devnet`, `mainnet-beta`, `testnet`
- Possible values for Hashes-per-tick: `Int` value if you want some number else `Sleep` for `None`.
- Given command will modify the `Cluster` type to `Development` and `Hashes per Tick` to `None`

You can verify the same using the below command.

```
solana-ledger-tool --ledger OUPUT_DIRECTORY genesis
```

For more options, you can use --help to get full details.

```
solana-ledger-tool modify-genesis --help
```

Comment: Give that you found the necessary arguments, I'm guessing you figured out that the subcommands each have their own help. But, I'll elaborate incase others stumble upon this.

In the initial screenshot you posted, `solana-ledger-tool --help` will show all the available subcommands for `solana-ledger-tool`. Then, supposing you want to use the `modify-genesis` subcommand, you can then run `solana-ledger-tool modify-genesis --help` to see the additional help and available arguments for `modify-genesis`.

Comment: Yeah forgot to mention this. Thanks I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are good resources that could help out, have you tried:

- https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start
- https://lib.rs/crates/solana-genesis

I shared this links because you said there were no resources btw..

Comment: I said no resources on how to use `solana-ledger-tool`